# How ot overwrite same files names after changing the files sizes?

Tags: c#, winforms

In a new class i added two methods : ChangeSize and ResizeImage

```
using ImageMagick;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Weather
{
    public class RadarPixels
    {
        public RadarPixels(string[] imagesToChangeSize,Bitmap image1, Bitmap image2)
        {
            ChangeSize(imagesToChangeSize);
            ReadSetPixels(image1, image2);
        }
        private void ReadSetPixels(Bitmap image1, Bitmap image2)
        {
            int tolerance = 64;
            for (int x = 0; x < image1.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < image1.Height; y++)
                {
                    Color pixelColor = image1.GetPixel(x, y);
                    // just average R, G, and B values to get gray. Then invert by 255.
                    int invertedGrayValue = 255 - (int)((pixelColor.R + pixelColor.G + pixelColor.B) / 3);
                    if (invertedGrayValue > tolerance) { invertedGrayValue = 255; }
                    // this keeps the original pixel color but sets the alpha value
                    image1.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(invertedGrayValue, pixelColor));
                }
            }
            // composite image1 on top of image2
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image2))
            {
                g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
                g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                g.DrawImage(image1, new Point(0, 0));
            }

            image2.Save(@"d:\mynewbmp.bmp");
            image1.Dispose();
            image2.Dispose();
        }

        private void ChangeSize(string[] images)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < images.Length; i++)
            {
                Bitmap bmpResized = ResizeImage(Image.FromFile(images[i]), 512, 512);
                bmpResized.Save(images[i]);
                bmpResized.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Image image, int width, int height)
        {
            var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
            var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

            destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
            {
                graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

                using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
                {
                    wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
                    graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
                }
            }

            return destImage;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the saving line in the ChangeSize method : i want to keep the same folder and files names and overwrite the existing files with the new sized files.

```
bmpResized.Save(images[i]);
```

before that i used to save it like this : and this is was working fine :

```
bmpResized.Save(@"d:\sized\" + Path.GetFileName(images[i]));
```

but when i try to overwrite the files i'm getting exception error on the line :

```
bmpResized.Save(images[i]);

System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.'

System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=A generic error occurred in GDI+.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename)
   at Weather.RadarPixels.ChangeSize(String[] images) in D:\Csharp Projects\Weather\RadarPixels.cs:line 56
   at Weather.RadarPixels..ctor(String[] imagesToChangeSize, Bitmap image1, Bitmap image2) in D:\Csharp Projects\Weather\RadarPixels.cs:line 20
   at Weather.Form1..ctor() in D:\Csharp Projects\Weather\Form1.cs:line 113
   at Weather.Program.Main() in D:\Csharp Projects\Weather\Program.cs:line 19
```

the files in the array images :

[image: images files names in array]

this is how i'm using it in form1 :

```
RadarPixels rp = new RadarPixels(radarImages,
                new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(@"D:\123.png")),
                new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(@"D:\2.jpg")));
```

Maybe the problem is because i'm displaying the images in pictureBox before changing the sizes ? maybe because the images are in use ?

Comment: 99.9% of the time, when using GDI, 'a generic error occured' means that the directory you are trying to save to doesn't have the proper permissions. Typically, you need to make sure that the directory is allowing you or the app to modify files. Or, maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655045/externalexception-0x80004005-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi

Comment: use sysinternals procmon to watch the IO your program is doing

Comment: ny guess, you still have the file open

Comment: Don't use `Image.FromFile()`, possibly, ever. Replace with `Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes([Image path])), true, false);`. No opened file stream, correct ICM information (when available) and no useless validation of the Bitmap -- Note that this: `image2.Save(@"d:\mynewbmp.bmp");` generates a PNG image, not a BMP image